# RegSetValueEx function writing gibberish

Tags: c++, winapi, registry, windows-ce

I am using the RegSetValueEX in the following code and it is setting the value to incomprehensible chars (chinese looking). I'm guessing something with the whole beautiful world of encoding?

```
HKEY regKey;
std::string newIP = "192.168.1.2";

Result = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("Comm\\VMINI1\\Parms\\TcpIp"), 0, 0, &regKey);
if (Result == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    Result = RegSetValueEx(regKey, TEXT("IPAddress"), 0, REG_SZ, (const BYTE*)newIP.c_str(), newIP.size() + 1);
    if (Result == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cout << "Done!";
    }
}
```

When I look at the registry entry however, the ip address is not set to the value supplied, it is random characters. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `std::string` which is ANSI, but you're probably compiling with `UNICODE` defined.  This means that you [RegSetValueEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724923%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will actually be calling `RegSetValueExW` (the unicode version).

```
HKEY regKey;
std::wstring newIP = TEXT("192.168.1.2");     // Use a wide string

Result = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("Comm\\VMINI1\\Parms\\TcpIp"), 0, 0, &regKey);
if (Result == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    Result = RegSetValueEx( regKey, 
        TEXT("IPAddress"), 
        0, 
        REG_SZ, 
        (const BYTE*)newIP.c_str(), 
        ( newIP.size() + 1 ) * sizeof( wchar_t ) );    // note the size change
    if (Result == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cout << "Done!";
    }
}
```

Comment: This code fails, if `UNICODE` is not defined. You are explicit about the strings character type by using `std::wstring`, so you should also be explicit when calling Win API: `RegOpenKeyExW`, `RegSetValueExW`. The `TEXT` macro should be replaced by wide-char prefix, e. g. `L"192.168.1.2"`.

Answer (score 5):

`std::string` uses `char` only.  Most Win32 API functions, including `RegOpenKeyEx()` and `RegSetValueEx()`, use `TCHAR` instead (as evident by your use of the `TEXT()` macro).  `TCHAR` maps to either `char` or `wchar_t`, and `RegSetValueEx()` maps to either `RegSetValueExA()` (Ansi) or `RegSetValueExW()` (Unicode), depending on whether the app is being compiled for Unicode or not.

In your case, I suspect that the app is being compiled for Unicode, so your data is mismatching what `RegSetValueEx()` is expecting.

Since you are working with `char` data, you should change your code to call `RegSetValueExA()` directly instead so there is no mismatch:

```
std::string newIP = "192.168.1.2";

Result = RegSetValueExA(regKey, "IPAddress", 0, REG_SZ, (const BYTE*)newIP.c_str(), newIP.length() + 1);
```

Otherwise, change your code to use `std::wstring` and `RegSetValueExW()` instead:

```
std::wstring newIP = L"192.168.1.2";

Result = RegSetValueExW(regKey, L"IPAddress", 0, REG_SZ, (const BYTE*)newIP.c_str(), (newIP.length() + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t));
```

Comment: I used std::wstring since windows CE 7 didn't have RegSetValueExA available. This worked well, my mind just starts thrashing when the whole ASCII and UNICODE problem comes about.